# Creating a variable from a ColdFusion form and using it between pages

Tags: forms, variables, coldfusion

**INTRODUCTION:**
Hello any and all,

I am trying to select a variable from Page 1 on Page 3 in Coldfusion. After looking into variable passing with CF, I have come across a few ways to pass with session or global variables, but am not sure if these are good methods for what I am trying to do.

**PROBLEM:**
The reason I am unsure of which is the best way to pass the variable is because the end user will be using this form multiple times a day and I am afraid of session variables not clearing properly from end users not successfully closing their sessions.

**OBJECTIVE:**
The Object of my form is to update information in my DB by pulling a Customer's Order ID. On my first page, I have the following form so that the end user can search by the Customer's Order ID and pull the customer's current information

```
    <cfform action="searchresults.cfm" method="post">
    <label for="Search" style="color: #fff !Important;"> Customer's OrderID:</label>
    <cfinput type="text" name="search" id="search" required="Yes" message="Please enter 
     an OrderID." class=" form-control" >         
        <input style="margin-top:20px;" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn red-btn">
    </cfform>
```

On my Page 3, I have a CFQUERY that I am using to update the DB based around the search variable from the form on page 1.

```
   <cfquery name="updateform" datasource="collinsmobile">
    
            UPDATE Table
        
            SET
        
        FName= <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.FName#" />
        LName = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.LName#" />
        CustomerEmail = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.CustomerEmail#" />
        CustomerPhone = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.CustomerPhone#" />
        CAddress = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.CAddress#" />
        City = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.City#" />
        St = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.State#" />
        Zip = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#form.Zip#" /> 
    
            Where OrderID= '#search#'

            </cfquery>
```

If Anyone could please help me to understand the best method to go about using the "search" variable for my query or point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it!

**Note:**
My Page 2 is called "searchresults.cfm" and is a query for page 1 as well as a proper form  for the final update query on page 3. I felt as though it was too much code and irrelevant to post but can supply code if needed!

Comment: One way you could do this, and isolate each form, even multiple forms in the same session, is to use hidden variables in the form.  Page 2 would contain a hidden version of the variables from Page 1.  When you get to the Page3 processor, use those hidden variables.  Make sure they exist with structKeyExists(form, "search") and if false, just route them to Page 1 (the search form).   If it doesn't have to be in the form, just append the value (?search=mysearchstring) to all the links you are building that redirect from the query results to the Page3 processing.

Comment: Thank you so much @WillBelden, this ended up helping me get to where I need to! I ended up doing as you said and using a Hidden form variable to pass it along. I had used hidden variables in the past but had completely forgot about using them for this, so thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

This more of a comment, but it is too long to fit in

Instead of

```
<cfinput type= "hidden" name="TestResult" id="TestResult" value=#TestResult# />
```

Consider

```
<input type= "hidden" name="TestResult" value="#encodeForHTMAttribute(TestResult)#">
```

**Why is this better?**

Starting with `<cfinput`

1. cfform is really a poor technology
2. You weren't even using it

Next `id=`

This is for css/javascript interactions. That does not apply here

Next `value=#TestResult#`

1. Values are supposed to be quoted
2. It is important to escape values because they could have characters that would break your code

Last `/>`

XHTML is dead

Answer (score 3):

The Answer I used for this was on account of Will Belden's comment. I ended up passing a Hidden Variable through my second page's form via:

```
<cfset TestResult = #search# />

<cfinput type= "hidden" name="TestResult" id="TestResult" value=#TestResult# />
```

The combination of a CFSET and a Hidden Variable was able to get me where I need to.